# WPF Setting effect of root control template with binding properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class that uses a shader to modify how it's rendered. I want to bind the Fill and Outline properties of the shader effect with the Fill and Outline properties of the base control.

The xaml below has no effect. The shader works but the properties aren't bound.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:RCTLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <effects:SpriteFontEffect Fill="{Binding Fill}" Outline="{Binding Outline}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:RCTLabel}">

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The code below does work but I'd prefer to bind the controls within xaml instead of within code.

```
SpriteFontEffect shader;

public RCTLabel() {
    shader = new SpriteFontEffect();
    Effect = shader;
}

private static void OnFillChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var element = (RCTLabel)sender;
    element.shader.Fill = element.Fill;
}
private static void OnOutlineChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var element = (RCTLabel)sender;
    element.shader.Outline = element.Outline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This binding expression just binds the Fill property to the Fill property of *the same SpriteFontEffect instance*! (Think of *int i = 2; i = i;* )

```
Fill="{Binding Fill}"
```

To bind to the Fill property of `RCTLabel`, use RelativeSource:

```
Fill="{Binding Fill, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RCTLabel}}"
```

[Here](https://wpftutorial.net/BindingExpressions.html) is a good reference for DataBinding Expressions in WPF.

Comment: Thanks this works! The only thing missing is the `local:` in front of the RCTLabel AncestorTypes.